# Is installing LXDE in ubuntu is equivalent to installing a fresh copy of Lubuntu?

Tags: installation, lubuntu

Is installing LXDE in ubuntu is equivalent to installing a fresh copy of Lubuntu?

My computer is 2005 Made,Intel D 101 Processor with 512 MB RAM and 80 GB Hard disk. Dual Boot with XP.

I feel a bit slow and have Ubuntu with LXDE desktop now.

Comment: LXDE is a desktop environment; if you choose the LXDE environment at the time of login then yes it's equivalent to Lubutnu. BTW the only difference between these various flavors of ubuntu is the desktop environmet(DE). :)

Comment: Yes and no it installs LXDE but there are subtle diferences between the LXDE and the Lubuntu sessions.

Answer (score 3):

There are packages that provide the LXDE desktop environment for an Ubuntu system that is already installed without LXDE. Usually, the best one to install is `lubuntu-desktop`. This does give you the same software that you'd have if you installed Lubuntu from scratch. But it does not *uninstall* the other software present on your system, and it does not reset settings, or clear out users' home directories, or repartition, or any of the other things that might happen when actually installing Lubuntu (or Ubuntu or any other Ubuntu derivative).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. Like Eliah Kagan mentioned, installing lubuntu-desktop on an ubuntu installation does not remove the other packages normally installed with ubuntu but not with lubuntu.

So while using a lighter window manager will help improve performance it will not be as fast as a clean lubuntu installation.

It's a question of deciding between speed and functionality.

See [Lubuntu_vs_Ubuntu](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Lubuntu_vs_Ubuntu)
and [Which *buntu to pick?](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/whichbuntu)